# How to setup .NET 4.5.x in GitHub actions windows runner

Tags: .net, github-actions, pipeline, .net-4.5, cicd

I'm trying to implement CICD for a .NET framework project which is based on .NET 4.5.x but GitHub actions `setup/dotnet` is not working as it couldn't find 4.5 in dotnet release index

I've tried to look for alternative by switching to windows-2019 runner from windows-latest and hoping to alteast use other dotnet version like 4.8 having backward compatability to build and test my dotnet 4.5 based project in github actions.

I'v tried to use `-f net45` with `dotnet build` to get that working but got the reference error for some nuGet packages.

Is there a way to build and test a dotnet 4.5 based project on GitHub actions windows runner?